# Exclude file from project in Visual Studio IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2022

When i exclude a file in a project, the icons of the files stay in the Solution panel but are updated with a small red circle meaning they are excluded, if i do this with another project the files just disappear, why?, in the picture the second project is where the files disappear when they are excluded.

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the file > Properties > General > Exclude From Build

This will keep your file in the Project so it can be viewed but will exclude it from build.